# Terraform AWS RDS fails when creating DB instances with hardcoded RDS cluster ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform

i'm trying to create a if/else statement for Terraform AWS RDS Cluster.  I have something like this working-ish:

```
module "aws" {
  # false = "0" and true = "1"
  create_from_snapshot = "1"
  snapshot_identifier = "db-final-snapshot"
}

# Normal deployment
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "cluster" {
  count = "${1 - var.create_from_snapshot}"
  cluster_identifier = "${var.db_name}"
}

# Creation from a snapshot
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "cluster_from_snapshot" {
  count = "${var.create_from_snapshot}"
  cluster_identifier = "${var.db_name}"
  snapshot_identifier = "${var.snapshot_identifier}"
}
```

However i'm having problems trying to define the `cluster_identifier` inside of the cluster instances, the first situation doesn't work uniformly for both cases while the second requires two `terraform apply` statements:

```
# Everything works fine, but then 'cluster' isn't defined 
# if using the 'cluster_from_snapshot' resource
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instance" {
  cluster_identifier = "${aws_rds_cluster.cluster.id}"
}

# This throws and error on 'terraform apply'
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instance" {
  cluster_identifier = "${var.db_name}"
}
```

Later on the command line ...

```
$> terraform apply
.... logs...
module.aurora.aws_rds_cluster.cluster_from_snapshot: 
    Creation complete after 50s (ID: testing)

Error: Error applying plan:
aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instance.0: error creating RDS DB 
    Instance: DBClusterNotFound, could not find DB Cluster: testing
aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instance.1: error creating RDS DB 
    Instance: DBClusterNotFound, could not find DB Cluster: testing

$> terraform apply # instance 0 & 1 get created no problem
```

Advice on creating a resource identifier for instances that would apply in both situations would be appreciated, but i'm really curious if there's something special about `${aws_rds_cluster.cluster.id}` (maybe it includes routing information?) that makes it different from a normal hard coded string or the variable, or is there just a timing lang?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't using the same "count attribute trick" on your inaws_rds_cluster_instance acceptable? I mean like you do with aws_rds_cluster, keep two resources and toggle them with count.

Comment: Apparently terraform 12 will bring support for null values, which I guess will allow you to do this: snapshot_identifier = "${var.create_from_snapshot == 1 ? var.snapshot_identifier : null}" and get away with a single aws_rds_cluster. There is this long thread on GitHub: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5471 about the lack of the null value in HCL; the final comment announces the upcoming support.

Comment: Yeah i'm looking forward to Terraform 12, but I ended up going with your first comment.  In that `db_instance_count > 1` I didn't think I could solve it the same way when `count = {0 | 1}`... but then I remembered multiplication exists.  Thank you very much!